# Typescript error: Create Alpha from RGBA as an Input with type number, not a string while using React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am using [react-colorful](https://github.com/omgovich/react-colorful) & using it's `<RgbaColorPicker />` component:

```
<RgbaColorPicker
  className="custom-pointers"
  color={selectedColor.rgba}
  onChange={(rgba: Rgba) =>
    updateBackground({
      transparent: false,
      selectedColor: {
        id: nanoid(),
        rgba,
      },
    })
  }
/>
```

This method requires `color` prop which requires `Rgba` type:

```
type Rgba = {
    r: number
    g: number
    b: number
    a: number
}
```

I have an input for alpha like:

```
<input
  className="text-center w-7 text-blue-gray-500"
  value={selectedColor.rgba.a}
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    if (value === '' || regex0to1.test(value))
      updateBackground({
        selectedColor: {
          ...selectedColor,
          rgba: {
            ...selectedColor.rgba,
            a: value,
          },
        },
      })
  }}
/>
```

Which works by taking all inputs required for alpha from `0.0` to `1.0` including all decimal places in between.

However, this also makes type of `a` equal to `string` which I cannot have as I need its type to be a `number` because that's the requirement of the `color` prop in `<RgbaColorPicker />`.

If I try to do `a: Number(value)` in the alpha input then I cannot enter an empty string or a decimal point in the input as `Number('')` is equal to `0` & `Number(1.)` is equal to `1`.

So how do I solve it whilst keeping the type of alpha as a `number`?

Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-sketch-picker-ouz5t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of how to set alpha perfectly. I had to setup local state as a `string | number`. String for empty string '' & number for other values. And I only take inputs from `regex0to1` so everything else filters out.

Here's how it looks like now:

```
const [alpha, setAlpha] = React.useState<string | number>(selectedColor.rgba.a)

<input
  className="text-center w-7 text-blue-gray-500"
  value={alpha}
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    if (value === '' || regex0to1.test(value)) {
      setAlpha(value)
      if (value !== '')
        updateBackground({
          selectedColor: {
            ...selectedColor,
            rgba: {
              ...selectedColor.rgba,
              a: parseFloat(value),
            },
          },
        })
    }
  }}
/>
```

The sandbox has been updated with new changes → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-sketch-picker-ouz5t

**Edit:**

I ditched the above answer & created `AlphaInput.tsx` file:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import React from 'react'

import { regex0to1 } from '../constants'
import { useEventCallback } from '../hooks'

const escapeNonAlpha = (alpha: string) => alpha.replace(/^[^\d(\.\d+)?]$/gi, '')
const validAlpha = (alpha: string) => regex0to1.test(alpha)

type AlphaProps = {
    alpha: string
    onChange: (value: string) => void
    onBlur?: (value: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

type InputProps = Omit<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'alpha' | 'onChange' | 'onBlur'>

export const AlphaInput = observer(
    ({ alpha = '', onChange, onBlur, ...rest }: AlphaProps & InputProps) => {
        const [value, setValue] = React.useState(() => escapeNonAlpha(alpha))
        const onChangeCallback = useEventCallback<string>(onChange)
        const onBlurCallback = useEventCallback<React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>>(onBlur)

        const handleChange = React.useCallback(
            (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                const inputValue = escapeNonAlpha(e.target.value)
                setValue(inputValue)
                if (validAlpha(inputValue)) onChangeCallback(inputValue)
            },
            [onChangeCallback]
        )

        const handleBlur = React.useCallback(
            (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                if (!validAlpha(e.target.value)) setValue(escapeNonAlpha(alpha))
                onBlurCallback(e)
            },
            [alpha, onBlurCallback]
        )

        React.useEffect(() => {
            setValue(escapeNonAlpha(alpha))
        }, [alpha])

        return <input {...rest} value={value} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} />
    }
)
```

This allows me to `onBlur` & if it is an invalid value, then it goes back. It also doesn't call `updateBackground` on incorrect values like `""` or `"0."`.

The codesandbox shows complete example → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-sketch-picker-ouz5t?file=/src/HexRgbaBox/AlphaInput.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Use input pattern, update background only if pattern is valid && number > 0

```
<input
    className="text-center w-7 text-blue-gray-500"
    type="text" 
    inputmode="decimal" 
    pattern="0+([.][0-9]+)?|1([.]0)?"
    value={selectedColor.rgba.a}
    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (
            e.target.validity.valid && 
            !!Number(e.target.value) // Exclude 0
        ) {
            const { value } = e.target
            updateBackground({
                selectedColor: {
                    ...selectedColor,
                    rgba: {
                        ...selectedColor.rgba,
                        a: Number(value)
                    },
                },
            })
        } else {
            // Just set state for controlled input
            // Add warning label for invalid input number in view
        }
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This isn't working the same reason my above code wasn't. `e.target.validity.valid` is `true` when the `value` is `0` or `` (empty string) or `0.`. In all cases, it makes `a` to be `0` as `Number(0)`, `Number('')` & `Number('0.')` is `0` :)

Comment: No worries Filip. I got the answer :)

Comment: sorry regex match floating between 0 and 1, updated condition:

if (e.target.validity.valid && !!Number(e.target.value)) { ...